# AR Quick Look in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, augmented-reality, arquicklook

I´m trying to use [AR Quick Look](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/previewing_a_model_with_ar_quick_look) in SwiftUI. I don't find any tutorial - only tutorials about AR Quick Look and UIKit. I new to Swift Development so I don't know exactly how to place UIKit views inside SwiftUI views.

Here the code with UIKit I want to display in SwiftUI:

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let previewController = QLPreviewController()
        previewController.dataSource = self
        present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int { return 1 }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myScene", ofType: "reality") else { fatalError("Couldn't find the supported input file.") }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }    
}
```